# Docker-Compose Multiple Local Environments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently using `docker-compose` for local development and a local test environment. The latter is clone of the development environment, with a few different `ENV` values. I'm looking to be able to spin up a testing environment, run my tests in the background and continue working in my development environment in the mean time. Here's what I'm currently working with:

**common.yml**

```
api-code:
    build: api
    volumes:
        - ../../:/var/www/api/

api-php:
    build: php
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"

api-web:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/ssl:/var/ssl

api-db:
    build: pg
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"

api-memcached:
    build: memcached
    ports:
        - "11211:11211"
```

**development**

```
api:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-code

php:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-php
    volumes_from:
        - api

memcached:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-memcached
    env_file:
        - .env.dev

artisan:
    build: ../../services/artisan
    volumes_from:
        - api
    env_file:
        - .env.dev

composer:
    build: ../../services/composer
    volumes_from:
        - api
    links:
        - artisan:artisan
    env_file:
        - .env.dev

nginx:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-web
    links:
        - php:php
    volumes_from:
        - api
    volumes:
        - ../../services/nginx/sites/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf

pg:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-db
    env_file:
        - .env.dev
```

**testing**

```
api:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-code

php:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-php
    volumes_from:
        - api

memcached:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-memcached
    env_file:
        - .env.test

codeception:
    build: ../../services/codeception
    volumes_from:
        - api
    links:
        - nginx:nginx
    env_file:
        - .env.test
    extra_hosts:
        - "site-test.whatever.com:xx.xx.xx.xx"

artisan:
    build: ../../services/artisan
    volumes_from:
        - api
    env_file:
        - .env.test

composer:
    build: ../../services/composer
    volumes_from:
        - api
    links:
        - artisan:artisan
    env_file:
        - .env.test

nginx:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-web
    links:
        - php:php
    volumes_from:
        - api
    volumes:
        - ../../services/nginx/sites/site-test.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-test.conf

pg:
    extends:
        file: ../../services/common.yml
        service: api-db
    env_file:
        - .env.test
```

I'm new to Docker, so I think this is likely a really naive approach, but for now, it's working. The downside is I can only bring `up` one environment at a time. When I want to run tests, I have to stop working until tests finish.

I'm not sure how to bring up the test environment without specifying a `volume` to map into the container. According to [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/), I'm reading them as I can run `docker-compose -f testing.yml up -d`, where in my `testing.yml` file I would not specify a `volume` on the `api` container. When I do that, obviously there's no code in the container, so everything else blows up.

How can I build the `api` container with code that's immutable from outside the container? I tried building development first and then running `docker-compose -f testing.yml up -d` with no luck. I have also tried referencing the local api image with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to include any files in the images , you use `ADD` or `COPY` in the `Dockerfile`.  You can override these files with a volume later for the dev environment.

You can also set the project name to make sure the environments don't overlap: http://docs.docker.com/compose/#Multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host

Comment: You're right, what I was missing was the notion of _build context_ which I must have glanced over [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).